# Convert normal random variable into beta random variable in STATA

Tags: normal-distribution, stata, beta-distribution

I need to generate two random variables - lognormal and beta distributed - while ensuring that the correlation between the two variables is -0.3.

I generated two normal random variables with -0.3 correlation as follows;

```
matrix C = (1, -0.3 \ -0.3, 1)
drawnorm x y, mean(0.921, 0) sds(0.174,1) corr(C)
// Here x is normal rv with mean 0.921 and sd 0.174 while y is a standard normal rv.
```

Converting x to lognormal is simple. I do this

```
gen price = exp(x)
// price is now the lognormal(0.921, 0.174)
```

Problem is in converting y~$N(0,1)$ to $beta(\alpha,\beta)$. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Some ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32718752/how-to-generate-correlated-uniform0-1-variables).

Comment: There are many different ways to do this.  Perhaps you can get the most control over them by using a [tag:copula].

Comment: Cross-posted on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52194343/convert-normal-random-variable-into-beta-random-variable-in-stata).

Comment: Are you aware that when you begin with two Normal variates of correlation $\rho$ and transform at least one of them nonlinearly--as will be necessary here--the correlation of the transformed variables is unlikely to equal $\rho$?  In light of this fact, is your question really about how to transform a Normal variate into a Beta variate or is it about how to create a lognormal, Beta pair with a desired correlation?

Comment: @whuber good point! Eventually I need lognormal and beta pair with desired correlation. I was hoping that I will adjust the correlation between normals (using trial and error) to get the desired correlation between lognormal and beta. I have been trying to understand copulas and how to implement this in Stata but things seem to not make sense so far.

Comment: Your approach sounds like it's tantamount to using a Gaussian copula.

Comment: @whuber I read a bit about Gaussian copula and I think I have the basic idea now. Do you have any idea how would I implement this in Stata? I am trying to avoid writing a program for this and probably use some canned program for this. Any leads?

Comment: See https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/794/919.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I was able to generate these variables;

```
matrix      C = (1, -0.32 \ -0.32, 1) // Matrix defining the correlation between two vars
drawnorm    x y, mean(0.921, 0) sds(0.174,1) corr(C) // Generate two multivariate normal vars with specified dependency
// Here x is normal rv with mean 0.921 and sd 0.174 while y is a standard normal rv.
```

Converting x to lognormal is simple. I do this

```
gen price = exp(x)
// price is now the lognormal(0.921, 0.174)
```

To convert y (a standard normal rv) I generated a normal cdf of y as follows;

```
gen         z2 = normal(y)
```

Then I used invibeta function to generate beta density with parameters a and b as follows;

```
gen yield = invibeta(a, b, z2)
```

The above process generates price (lognormal) and yield (beta) with correlation of -0.30.